# pom.xml how to solve error in seam booking sample project, Eclipse Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, seam

I just started to learn JBoss Seam Framework and I've never use Maven. I downloaded from [this page](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam2/Seam2DistributionDownloads) JBoss Seam 2.2.0. GA and I want to run sample *booking project* in eclipse.

I used **import** option with **Existing Maven Project**. 
Next I right-click on project and I select **Run As -> Maven install...** console display:

```
...
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.372s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 22 18:43:01 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/73M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but in bookmarks Problems is:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
maven-resources-plugin prior to 2.4 is not supported by m2e. Use maven-resources-plugin version 2.4 or later.   pom.xml /jboss-seam-booking line 8  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

I don't know how to solve it. 
I don't try to use **Maven build** option beacuse I don't know what should be in 'Goals'.

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.jboss.seam.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-seam-booking</artifactId>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.GA</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

</project>
```

I use Eclipse Indigo SR2, maven was downloaded probably with *JBoss Tools* for Eclipse.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your pom. This will override the maven-resources-plugin version defined in the parent pom.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Since the parent does not seem to have any special configuration for the maven-resources-plugin, but just declares the version number as well, this should be ok to do.

Comment: Thanks for help! :) One more question, can you tell me how to run this project? I don't know how to set **Run Configurations** (define goals).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with the jboss pom. It is using a plugin that is incompatible with m2e.

Comment: Do you know how to install older version of this plugin on eclipse? During **Maven install**  console displays:
_maven-ear-plugin:2.4.2:generate-application-xml_
_maven-resources-plugin:2.2:resources (default-resources)_
_maven-ear-plugin:2.4.2:ear (default-ear)_
_maven-install-plugin:2.1:install (default-install)_

Comment: You generally install M2E via the Eclipse plug in manager. In terms of the JBoss pom, talk to them.